# How to mount loop devices in Travis CI

Tags: kernel, mount, travis-ci

I'm trying to run the following command in Travis CI:

```
$ sudo mount -o loop,offset=62914560 2014-09-09-wheezy-raspbian.img /home/travis/build/3DprintFIT/OctoPi/src/workspace/mount
```

But however I end up with:

```
mount: Could not find any loop device. Maybe this kernel does not know
   about the loop device? (If so, recompile or `modprobe loop'.)
```

I'm trying to do:

```
sudo modprobe loop
```

But that fails. I do not longer have the error message, but I assume it's because Travis CI environment is running in a container and you simply cannot load kernel modules from there.

Do I have  mount the device with FUSE instead (and how?) or can I do something about it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems travis-ci does not support loopfs currently.

https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/1119

Which means fuseiso doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Travis CI doesn't support this, due to their current virtualisation technology. However, you should be able to use [vido](https://github.com/g2p/vido) to overcome this limitation; it's a wrapper around User Mode Linux that *should* allow you to mount a loop device using another instance of the kernel.

You should be able to run:

```
vido --uml -- /bin/sh -c my_script.sh
```

to allow `my_script.sh` to mount a loopback device. Make sure you install `vido` and its dependencies (including Python 3.3+) in your `before_install` section!